# Fortran: Using C function in Intel Fortran x64

Tags: c, fortran

My data file (thedata.txt) has 10 locations such as:

```
492484.94 4414814.5
418558.31 4387130.8
488518.45 4425324.5
514821.34 4414303.1
474606.53 4452659.5
488970.51 4462154.6
487880.97 4423944.5
508027.28 4437213.5
492079.38 4429661.5
449220.47 4396761.5
```

The C file (bidist.c) calculates 10*9/2=45 bilateral distances:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bidist(double thedata[][2], double d2[][1], double ndata[1][1])
{
  register int i,j,k;
  double x,y;
  k=0;
  for(i=0;i<ndata[0][0];i++) {
    for(j=i+1;j<ndata[0][0];j++) {
      x = (thedata[i][0]-thedata[j][0]);
      y = (thedata[i][1]-thedata[j][1]);
      d2[k][0]= (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)));
      k++;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use the "bidist" function to print the "d2" vector in Fortran. I write a Fortran code (main.f90):

```
program distance
 implicit none
 real, dimension(10,2) :: thedata
 real, dimension(45) :: d2
 integer :: i
 open(10, file='thedata.txt', status='old')
 rewind(10)
 do i=1,10
  read(10,*) thedata(i,1:2)
 end do
 call bidist(thedata,d2,10)
 print*, d2
end program distance
```

I ran "cl -c bidist.c" and "ifort -c main.f90". Then I did "ifort -o mymain bidist.obj main.obj". But I have the LNK2019 error. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Would it not be simpler to just rewrite the 10-line function in FORTRAN?

Comment: You're right. But I want to understand how to use C functions in Fortran. My actual C source code is very large.

Comment: @BillTP, perhaps the actual error text would help get closer to an answer.  The LNK2019 error is usually accompanied by text like: "unresolved external symbol 'symbol' referenced in function 'function'".  That text might indicate other libraries (etc.) might be needed to support the C code.

Comment: @Mahonri, -out:mymain.exe -subsystem:console bidist.obj main.obj main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol BIDIST referenced in function MAIN__ mymain.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.

Comment: @BillTP, it appears that there is a function the linker knows as 'MAIN__' that is referencing a symbol known as 'BIDIST' that is not found in the various object files being linked. Are you sure that the object file containing "bidist" is being linked?  Or, is the linker change the symbol (for some reason) to upper-case?  Are fortran functions case in-sensitive?  Perhaps you might change the function name from "bidist" to "BIDIST"?

Comment: What error do you get? bidist_ not found or something? Fortran does name mangling and you need to take care of that. Best way to interact with C is to use the ISO-C-Binging: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/C+interoperability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really recommend using `iso_c_binding` as @haraldkl has pointed out.

After saying this, there seems to be a few mistakes in your code.

1) You define the data and results to be of type `real` yet the `bidist` function is expecting doubles.

You might be calling the compiler with different definitions of real and integers, as in I know `ifort` can take `-r8` to say reals are 8-bytes. However I find this can come back to bite you (if you forget to add such flags when using other compilers, etc).

I would either use `select_kind` or `iso_fortran_env` or `iso_c_binding`:

**select_kind**

```
integer, parameter                   :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
real(kind=dp), dimension(10,2)       :: thedata
```

**iso_fortran_env**

```
use, intrinsic                       :: iso_fortran_env
integer, parameter                   :: dp = REAL64
real(kind=dp), dimension(10,2)       :: thedata
```

**iso_c_binding**

```
use, intrinsic                       :: iso_c_binding
real(kind=C_DOUBLE), dimension(10,2) :: thedata
```

2) The array definitions in `bidist` define array size in the wrong order. Remember C is row-major.

```
void bidist(double thedata[][10], double d2[], int ndata)
```

In this sense I would re-write the program along the following lines:

```
program distance

        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

        implicit none

        real(kind=C_DOUBLE), dimension(10,2) :: thedata
        real(kind=C_DOUBLE), dimension(45)   :: d
        integer :: i

        interface
            subroutine bidist(d1, d2, n) bind(C)
                import
                real(kind=C_DOUBLE), dimension(10,*), intent(in)    :: d1
                real(kind=C_DOUBLE), dimension(*),    intent(inout) :: d2
                integer(kind=C_INT), value,           intent(in)    :: n
            end subroutine bidist
        end interface

        thedata = 0.0
        d = 0.0
        i = 0

        open(10, file='thedata.txt', status='old')
        rewind(10)
        do i=1,10
                read(10,*) thedata(i,1:2)
        end do

        call bidist(thedata, d, 10)

        do i=1,45
                print*, i, d(i)
        end do
end program distance
```

And then bidist as:

```
void bidist(double thedata[][10], double d2[], int ndata)
{
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        double x = 0.0;
        double y = 0.0;


        for(i=0;i<ndata;i++) {
                for(j=i+1;j<ndata;j++) {
                        x = (thedata[0][i]-thedata[0][j]);
                        y = (thedata[1][i]-thedata[1][j]);
                        d2[k] = (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)));
                        k++;
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: The array bounds in the interface should be more like `thedata(10,*)` and `d2(*)`.

Comment: @VladimirF your right. Thanks. I tend not to do this myself, I allocate and pass pointers and the array shape instead.

Comment: Timothy, your code works (when I add the original include lines)! Thank you very much.